# Is there a way to secure whole swashbuckle UI, not just call api?

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I setup swashbuckle azure AD authentication and everything works (i.e. if I click authorise button, I can trigger Azure AD authentication and get token back to call the api).

I am wondering if there is a way to secure the whole page (i.e. as soon as the swagger UI page is loaded, it will automatically pick the selected scope and authenticate against azure AD)?

The idea is that only people that has a valid AD account can see the API definition and try thing out. With my swashbuckle implementation, seems everyone can see the API definition and only people passing authentication can try it.

This is my code so far:
Service config:

```
AddSwaggerGen(
                    c =>
                    {
                        c.ExampleFilters();

                        Dictionary<string, string> scopes = new Dictionary<string, string>
                        {
                            { "XXXX", "XXXX" }
                        };
                        c.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                        {
                            Type = SecuritySchemeType.OAuth2,
                            Flows = new OpenApiOAuthFlows
                            {
                                Implicit = new OpenApiOAuthFlow
                                {
                                    AuthorizationUrl = new Uri($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{_appSettings.AzureActiveDirectoryTenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize"),
                                    TokenUrl = new Uri($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{_appSettings.AzureActiveDirectoryTenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token"),
                                    Scopes = scopes

                                }
                            },
                            In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                            Name = "Authorization",
                             BearerFormat= "JWT",
                            Scheme = "bearer",
                        });
                        c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
                        {
                            {
                                new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                                {
                                    Reference = new OpenApiReference { Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme, Id = "oauth2" }
                                },
                                scopes.Keys.ToList()
                            }
                        });
                        c.OperationFilter<SecurityRequirementsOperationFilter>();
                       
                    }
                )
```

Then on UI:

```
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI(
     c => {
          c.OAuthClientId(_appSettings.ThunderClientId);
          c.OAuthUsePkce();
          c.OAuthScopeSeparator(" ");
          }
        )
```

Comment: look at this [article](https://medium.com/@niteshsinghal85/securing-swagger-in-production-92d0a045a5) and [this](https://medium.com/@niteshsinghal85/securing-swagger-ui-in-production-in-asp-net-core-part-2-dc2ae0f03c73). it explains the procedure to secure swagger ui in detail

Comment: We can check the if the user has the claims or token based on that we can allwo user to redirect or allow user to see the swagger URL.